# I've created a Java FX application in Netbeans and it doesn't offer the `open` option for my fxml file

Tags: netbeans, javafx, scenebuilder

Using `Netbeans 8.0.2` and `Java 1.8.0.72` I am given the option of creating a `Java FX FXML Application` and it all looks fine and it runs as expected. However, tutorials show an `open` option as well as the normal `edit` option for the `fxml` file that should open it using `Scene Builder`. I do not see that.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I had'nt installed `SceneBuilder`.

Download [SceneBuilder](http://gluonhq.com/open-source/scene-builder/), install it and try again. The `open` option appears.